# SQL find consecutive time by start and end date

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

Assume I'm having a database table employee_worksheet with data like below:

| ID | employee_id | time_start | time_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | 1 | '2024-01-02 7:00' | '2024-01-02 8:00' |
| #2 | 1 | '2024-01-02 9:00' | '2024-01-02 10:00' |
| #3 | 1 | '2024-01-02 10:05' | '2024-01-02 11:00' |
| #4 | 1 | '2024-01-02 11:05' | '2024-01-02 12:00' |
| #5 | 1 | '2024-01-02 1:00' | '2024-01-02 2:00' |

Given a specific record, for example employee_worksheet #3, how can I query to get the consecutive worksheets which include the worksheet #3? The consecutive worksheet should be considered if the start of the shift is not over 5 minutes of the end of the previous shift. The output would look likes:

| ID | employee_id | time_start | time_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #2 | 1 | '2024-01-02 9:00' | '2024-01-02 10:00' |
| #3 | 1 | '2024-01-02 10:05' | '2024-01-02 11:00' |
| #4 | 1 | '2024-01-02 11:05' | '2024-01-02 12:00' |

Thanks in advance.

I tried with the gaps and islands problem, but cannot find the case where we given a record in the middle of the consequence.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to consider the negative condition and exclude them.

For shifts a and b, they **do not** overlap is a.time_end < b.time_start or a.time_start > b.time_start

```
SELECT a.employee_id, a.time_start, a.time_end
  FROM employee_worksheet a JOIN employee_worksheet b
        ON NOT (a.time_end < b.time_start OR
                a.time_start > b.time_end)
WHERE b.employee_id = 3
```

To cope with the 5 minute gap that is permitted you can use the ADDDATE function

```
SELECT a.employee_id, a.time_start, a.time_end
  FROM employee_worksheet a JOIN employee_worksheet b
        ON NOT (a.time_end <= DATEADD(b.time_start,INTERVAL -5 MINUTE) OR
                a.time_start >= DATEADD(b.time_end,INTERVAL  5 MINUTE)
WHERE b.employee_id = 3
```